# Prove the following equality (similar to Hoeffding?)

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that a rv $X$ is such that $|X| \leq c$, $E[X] = 0$ and $E[X^2] = \sigma^2 < \infty$. Prove that for any $\theta > 0$
$$E\left[e^{\theta X} \right]\leq \exp\left(\sigma^2 \left(\frac{e^{\theta c} - 1 - \theta c}{c^2}\right)\right).$$

I am trying to prove the inequality using a similar approach to Hoeffding's lemma, but I am struggling to obtain the result. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Expand the left-hand side in Taylor series. Show your steps?

Comment: Sorry, do you mind explaining how that helps? Expanding the left hand side as a Taylor series gives $E[\sum_k \frac{(\theta X)^k}{k!}]$ right?

Comment: Yes. Then note that $E(X^k) \leq E(|X|^k) = E(|X|^2 \cdot |X|^{k-2})$ and use the assumptions

Comment: I don't quite understand what happens after this.. am I meant to use Cauchy-Schwarz to separate the $E(|X|^2)$ term?

Comment: You have $|X|\leq c$ and so this takes the care of $|X|^{k-2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y = X/c$. Then $Y \le 1$, $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$.

From the result in [1] (page 218 in the link), we have, for $s > 0$,
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{e}^{sY}] \le \mathrm{exp}((\mathrm{e}^{s} - s - 1)\mathbb{E}[Y^2])$$
which results in 
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{e}^{\theta X}] \le \mathrm{exp}(\sigma^2(\mathrm{e}^{\theta c} - \theta c - 1)/c^2)$$
where $\theta = s/c$. We are done.

[1] Boucheron, Lugosi, and Bousquet, "Concentration Inequalities".
http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/mlss_conc.pdf